# Read the pdf content?

Tags: android, pdf

able to open the pdf files . but dont know how to save the content of the pdf file in a array or something then i can show the pdf as i want. can anybody suggest me how to save the pdf content...is there any libraries to use?

following snippet shows how to open a pdf

```
            File file = new File("/sdcard/example1.pdf");

            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Log.e("path of the file",path.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use iText library..

iText is a Java library originally created by Bruno Lowagie which allows to create PDF, read PDF and manipulate them

here is the link.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: when i use iText library in android  public void read(){
   Log.e("i am in","read");
  try {
   PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/example1.pdf"));
   doc.open();
   doc.add(new Paragraph("Hellooooooooooooo"));
   doc.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (DocumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }  i got file not found exception

Comment: iText Library fetches all the text, but its not maintain images or table or lines(Graphics)...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mono for Android](http://android.xamarin.com/). It will enable you to develop for Android using C# and .NET and will let you install and access to the [iTextSharp library](http://itextsharp.com/)

The iTextSharp is a very extensive and well documented library for creating and manipulating adobe pdf documents.

Comment: thanks for the guidance...i've already used iText it works in java when comes to android getting filenotfound exception